# Where is the list of IDs which can be used with the TimeZone.getTimeZone API?

Tags: java, timezone

For the TimeZone API - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone(java.lang.String), where can I find the list of IDs which can be used as parameter here?

Comment: There's a method called [`TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getAvailableIDs()) (link taken right from the JavaDoc you've provided).

Comment: `ZoneId` is the newer and better API to use.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `TimeZone`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead as @Sweeper said, use `ZoneId` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). You want the `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()` method. And/or [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()` method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getAvailableIDs()

or you can also find the list of timezones here: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-timezone.html